# PHP - Get data from multi dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

Easy question ... but here it goes:

I have an array and I need to use the [0] index which represents the id of each user. But I can't seem to get it in a foreach statement.

```
$emails = $aTools->getUsers();
```

Below is a print_r of the above array '$emails'.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 72
        [1] => 
        [2] => email@yahoo.com
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 62
        [1] => 
        [2] => email@gmail.com
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 64
        [1] => 
        [2] => email@gmail.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 66
        [1] => 
        [2] => email@yahoo.com
    )
)
```

This is not working

```
$i = 0;
foreach($emails as $email)
{
    echo $email[$i][0];
    echo "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `[$i]` part and the entire variable `$i` and you are good to go -> `foreach($emails as $email) echo $email[0] . "<br>";`

Comment: Should have said too easy :) Thank you!

Comment: it's easy to confuse `for` syntax with `foreach`

Comment: @Rizier123 you want to add an answer?

Comment: @ciprian no, won't put an answer in for this one, there is already one with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time u're looping u'll get in $email on the entry table :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 72
        [1] => 
        [2] => email@yahoo.com
    )
```

Then

```
Array
(
    [0] => 62
    [1] => 
    [2] => email@gmail.com
)
```

ETC..

> So echo $email[$i][0] can't return the id u want.
>
> **$email[0] CAN.**

SOLUTION :

```
 foreach($emails as $email)
        echo $email[0];
```